# Selenium webdriver parallel test in MSTEST

Tags: selenium, mstest, webdriver

Quick question, is it possible to run parallel test using selenium webdriver C# and MSTEST?

If yes then how?

I have tried adding this to my local test settings but it didn't change anything, the tests still ran one at a time.

```
 <Execution parallelTestCount="2">
```

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Nobody who got an answer for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it was because i only has 1 test class with multiple methods. In anycase it works now and only change i can think of is that i have multiple test methods across multiple testclasses.